# Error at loading Slider Revolution 5.0 Extrensions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**I downloaded a template and open it directly, it gives me an error for the slider.** 
!! Error at loading Slider Revolution 5.0 Extrensions.
Local Filesystem Detected !
Put this to your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js"></script>
```

Again I uploaded to local server, there is no error but an empty slider. 
I checked the inspect element, it shows the errors in the below image:

[image: Inspect]

Comment: That's a `404` error, the files doesn't exist on the path you've specified.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're trying to get those files from a folder, `js`, in your source folder; that's not where they are located. With a quick Google search I found that those were located on another website, http://iccila.com.br.

The fixed `<script>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://www.iccila.com.br/js/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js">
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://www.iccila.com.br/js/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js">
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://www.iccila.com.br/js/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js>
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://www.iccila.com.br/js/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a cause of jQuery conflict. First I recommended upgrading your revolution slider.

Step to fix:

- Go to bakend and click Slider Revolution
- Click Global Setting.
- Click on buttons

> Insert JavaScript Into Footer:
>   Defer JavaScript Loading:

[image]

Comment: This helped me so well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js` and other js files you are adding are in the folder `js/vendor/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/` and also that the js folder is in the same folder as this page that you are trying to open.

=======

If it isn't then specify the exact location in place of `js/vendor/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with Magento Rev Slider.
The problem was the caching extension that I have used. Amasty Full Page Cache.
I disabled and tried and everything worked fine.

- So, I recommend you to check if all files exist with proper permission.
- Then check and see if the page is cached.
- Try and fully disable cache.
- Also disable Chrome or browser Cache

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add this to your page revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js to your files.
I had the same exact problem I solved it by downloading this revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js file and then adding it to the folder

Then the mentioned code should be added at the bottom of the page.

Basically just look at your folder and see if all the mentioned js files exist. If they don't download them and add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need server Environment to run Rev slider in local pc.
Like put all files in local host or upload in web server.
It will work.

Thanks